# when should we have Portlet-class to have an predefined class and a custom class

Tags: struts2, liferay, portlet

This is my Portlet.xml inside the existing project .
Could anybody please tell me when should we have Portlet-class to have an predefined class and a custom class ??

```xml
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>DataUpload</portlet-name>
    <display-name>DataUpload</display-name>
    <portlet-class>org.apache.struts2.portlet.dispatcher.Jsr168Dispatcher</portlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <name>viewNamespace</name>
        <value>/view</value>
    </init-param>
</portlet>

<portlet>
    <portlet-name>Reports</portlet-name>
    <display-name>Reports</display-name>
    <portlet-class>com.tata.ReportAction</portlet-class>
</portlet>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an ample question and hard to answer in its full sense. However, there are some rules that are almost always followed:

- If your portlet does use some Java framework (like Struts 2, JSF) it will almost certainly use a predefined [`javax.portlet.GenericPortlet`](http://www.bluesunrise.com/portlet-api/javax/portlet/GenericPortlet.html) subclass. All the processing is made by the framework and the portlet class has the sole purpose of redirecting the requests to the framework. This kind of portlet class is called *bridge*. In your example, your bridge is `org.apache.struts2.portlet.dispatcher.Jsr168Dispatcher`.
- If your portlet does use the Liferay MVC portlet and only show retrieved data in JSPs (without updating them), then you may not need to write your custom portlet class. You may not need another class because the [`com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc .MVCPortlet`](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.0/javadocs/com/liferay/util/bridges/mvc/MVCPortlet.html) class does present JSPs automatically. I will not explain it in detail, but that is the point. This is a rare situation, so do not think much about it.
- If your portlet does *not* use Liferay MVC but instead is written in plain JSR 286 API, then you will probably need to write your custom portlet class. It is because the default `render()`, `doView()` etc. methods of `GenericPortlet` are not enough to present JSPs.
- If your portlet does not use any Java generic framework, uses Liferay MVC and does process data by updating it, then you will probably need some custom subclass of `MVCPortlet`. This is so because the processing of data is made by methods called during the action phase. These methods (usually called "process action methods") are recognized by having two parameters of the types [`javax.portlet .ActionRequest`](http://www.bluesunrise.com/portlet-api/javax/portlet/ActionRequest.html) and [`javax.portlet .ActionResponse`](http://www.bluesunrise.com/portlet-api/javax/portlet/ActionResponse.html).

In your example, you have two portlets: one which uses Struts (so the portlet class just dispatches requests to Struts 2) and another one which uses a custom portlet class. This portlet class can either extend `GenericPortlet` or `MVCPortlet`. If it uses `GenericPortlet`, then it is inevitable to have a custom class. If it does use `MVCPortlet`, then this class probably has some process action methods.

I bet my answer is way too abstract, but I hope it gives you some ideas about other questions, more specific and answerable.